# Need some help with a XElement Query

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xelement

This query isn't working as I'm expecting it to. Anyone see the problem?

I'm trying to get an element by it's name, but it's not returning anything. Here is the specific part of the function I need some help with:

[image]

---

*Update*

The solution was to use an XName instead of a string. Like so:

```
var matchingElements = elements.Where(e => e.Name.Equals(XName.Get(name)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your line to:

```
elements.Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == name)
```

The `LocalName` part is the important part, as otherwise you are comparing equality of an `XName` with a `string`.  Remember, XML supports names of the style "prefix:element-name".  In that example, "prefix" is the identifier associated with the namespace returned by `e.Name.Namespace` and "element-name" is the identifier returned by `e.Name.LocalName`.

Comment: Interesting - I had a feeling it might have something to do with the namespace, I'll investigate further. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Kirk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114970/need-some-help-with-a-xelement-query/4115027#4115027) is right on the money. I wanted to point out a few issues with your code.

This line unnecessarily counts all the elements:

```
var hasMatch = matchingElements.Count() > 0;
```

You can replace it with `Any()` which will terminate early once an element is found:

```
var hasMatch = matchingElements.Any();
```

Next, having verified that `hasMatch` is `true` you should call `First()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()` since you know it has to have a value at that point.

Having said that, you could actually rewrite your code as follows:

```
var matchingElement = elements.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == name);
return (string)matchingElement;
```

Here casting to a `string` will return the value of the element if it was found, otherwise it would return `null`. The cast is used just in case it was `null` since you wouldn't be able to use `matchingElement.Value` which would throw a `NullReferenceException` if no element was found. You should also consider using `SingleOrDefault` if you expect only one element to exist.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I wasn't aware of the advantages of the .Any function. I appreciated you taking the time teach these optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the root namespace to the name of the element.
You can also try using the `XContainer.Descendants(XName)` method instead.